# while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) - how many loops are being performed?

Tags: php, mysql

if...

```
$query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE id > 100"
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

for this action:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ....
}
```

**is this doing 1 loop (iterated x times)?**

and for this one:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
foreach($row as $r){
   ...
}
```

**is this doing 2 loops (iterated x times)?**

where x is the number of results

---

EDIT:

ok thanks guys, ok I basically phrased this question really, really badly.

in retrospect it should have been

> 'does mysql_fetch_array() only return one
>   row each time it is called'

I an now happy that my understanding of mysql_fetch_array() was v. incorrect!

thanks for your time!

Comment: i'm unsure as to how mysql_fetch_array() performs. it's creating an array so i'm thinking it must be looping. I'm curious as to whether *while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))* can get manipulations ie str_irepalce() inside that initial loop

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I'm assuming mysql_fetch_array() perfroms a loop, so I'm interested in if using a while() in conjunction with it, if it saves a nested loop.

No. `mysql_fetch_array` just returns the next row of the result and advances the internal pointer. It doesn't loop. (Internally it may or may not use some loop somewhere, but that's irrelevant.)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   ...
}
```

This does the following:

1. `mysql_fetch_array` retrieves and returns the next row
2. the row is assigned to `$row`
3. the expression is evaluated and if it evaluates to `true`, the contents of the loop are executed
4. the procedure begins anew

> ```
> $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
> foreach($row as $r) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

This does the following:

1. `mysql_fetch_array` retrieves and returns the next row
2. the row is assigned to `$row`
3. `foreach` loops over the contents of the array and executes the contents of the loop as many times as there are items in the array

In both cases `mysql_fetch_array` does exactly the same thing. You have only as many loops as you write. Both constructs do not do the same thing though. The second will only act on one row of the result, while the first will loop over all rows.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many rows are returned in `$results`, and how many columns there are in `$row`?

Answer (score 1):

Considering only one row is returned, only one loop will be done in both cases. Though it will check for the loop entering condition twice on each.

Comment: see other comment: multiple rows, multiple cols

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: your program will go through the loop once for every row in the result set returned by the query. You can know in advance how many results there are by using `mysql_num_rows()`.

For the second one: this time you are only using *one row* of the result set and you are doing something for each of the *columns*. That's what the `foreach` language construct does: it goes through the body of the loop for each entry in the array `$row`. The number of times the program will go through the loop is knowable in advance: it will go through once for every column in the result set (which presumably you know, but if you need to determine it you can use `count($row)`).

Comment: ah ok sorry im not being clear about this, i'm after **how many loops** not how many iterations of the loop

Comment: In each of your examples there is only one loop. On the other hand, if you were to do `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { foreach ($row as $r) { ... } }` that would be two loops, one nested inside the other.

Comment: im not suggesting put the foreach() inside the while(), I'm just wondering whether it's equaly efficient to use a while() on the fetch_array() as loop through afterwards with foreach()

Comment: If I understand the way you're thinking about this, I think you have slightly the wrong idea about what the two pieces of code you quoted would do. The first one is what you would use if you had more than one row in the query result set and wanted to do something with each row. The second one is what you would use if you knew you would only have one row, and you wanted to do something with every column of that row. Doing `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { statements }` and doing `foreach($row as $r){ statements }` will not give you the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The first row:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

return php db resource.

The second row

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Loops all the records returned by the query.

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead
In that case the row has key=>value pairs.
In the while just put this:
`print_r($row)` and you will understand
If you use mysql_fetch_assoc the format of the row will be:

```
$row["column1_name"] = column1_value;  
$row["column2_name"] = column2_value;
```

For this one:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)  
foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {  
    ...  
}
```

You will get the firs row from the query and you will iterate all columns in the first result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one result. If you want to retrieve more than one row, you need to put the function call in a `while` loop.

Two examples:

This will only return the first row

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This will return one row on each loop, until no more rows are available from the result set

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //Do stuff with contents of $row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM table WHERE id > 100"
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array()) //here you can use many functions such as mysql_fetch_assoc() and other
 {
//It returns 1 row to your variable that becomes array and automatically go to the next result string
  Echo $row['col1']."|".Echo $row['col2']."|".Echo $row['col2'];
 }
}
```

Comment: ERROR:
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/MultiDatesPicker/getuser.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />