# While loop in if statement

Tags: php

I have bellow code which jobs announced which load only one record i have used while loop which doesn't work.

```
<?php
$job="SELECT * from jobs where job_exp_date>=now()";
$query=mysql_query($job);
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if($result==0) {
echo "Sorry We Don't have current openings. Thank you for your intreset";
}else{
echo"<table width=\"auto\">&nbsp;
<tr>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></p></th>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Location &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Expiry Date &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
</tr>";
while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>
    <td>";echo $result1['job_title']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <td>";echo $result1['job_location']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <td>";echo $result1['job_exp_date']; echo "</td>
</tr>"; } echo " 
</table>"; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed

Comment: Is it not "while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($result))"

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

to

```
$result=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php
    $job="SELECT * from jobs where job_exp_date>=now()";
    $query=mysql_query($job);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) 
    {
        echo "Sorry We Don't have current openings. Thank you for your intreset";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<table width=\"auto\">&nbsp;
        <tr>
            <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></p></th>
            <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Location &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
            <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Expiry Date &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
        </tr>";
        while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>";echo $result1['job_title']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td>";echo $result1['job_location']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td>";echo $result1['job_exp_date']; echo "</td>
                </tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table>"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$job="SELECT * from jobs where job_exp_date>=now()";
$query=mysql_query($job);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($rows==0) {
echo "Sorry We Don't have current openings. Thank you for your intreset";
}else{
echo"<table width=\"auto\">&nbsp;
<tr>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Title &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></p></th>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Location &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
    <th><p class=\"slide-title\"><strong>Expiry Date &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></strong></th>
</tr>";
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>
    <td>";echo $result['job_title']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <td>";echo $result['job_location']; echo "</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <td>";echo $result['job_exp_date']; echo "</td>
</tr>"; } echo " 
</table>"; 
 }
?>
```

Try this......when ever you want to check that query get a result or not use "mysql_num_rows"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try this code... it's helpful to you :-)]

Just minor error in your code. i had change just little bit change in your code and it's working fine...