# PHP while loop not printing all MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a PHP While() loop to display results from a SQL query inside a  menu. The SQL query should return 4 results but only 3 options appear in the drop down menu.

I fixed this problem temporarily by adding a 5th record that I didn't need displayed.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem properly? 
The while() loop seems to be stopping 1 record short.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE child = '1' AND code = '".$code."' ORDER BY description";
$products = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($results= mysql_fetch_array($products))
{                               
  echo '<option value="'.$results['id'].'">'.$results['description'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Try a "SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE child = '1' AND code = '".$code."' ORDER BY description" and see how many it returns

Comment: I've done mysql_num_rows and it's showing the right number, which is +1 more than the number of options.

Comment: The code you posted should not do such a thing as you describe. I would hazard that this is not the actual code you're using, and that in your actual code you have a mysql_result, mysql_fetch_row, mysql_fetch_array, mysql_fetch_object or some such call somewhere between the mysql_query and the while loop which removes the first result. There is no way that mysql_fetch_array skips the last result.

On a sidenote: you really SHOULD NOT be using the mysql extension anymore, it has been officially deprecated. Instead, you are advised to use either MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Or, the html code could get broken by data having html tags (for example `<`in description) and your browser might not display that option at all, try to check the source code to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @Tularis you were correct, there was a separate query being executed in the middle. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help for you:

In this article is very well explained, and it gives you other options.

[while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) - how many loops are being performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed)

Good luck!