# Pull data from the DB and display in a leaderboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have a leaderboard with the html and css codes given  below:

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;  
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
}


/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/
.leaderboard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 308px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, .3);

  h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 12px 13px 18px;

    & svg {
      width: 25px;
      height: 26px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }

  }

  ol {
    counter-reset: leaderboard;

    li {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 14px;
      counter-increment: leaderboard;
      padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);


      &::before {
        content: counter(leaderboard);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #c24448;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      mark {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #fff;

        &::before, &::after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          bottom: -11px;
          left: -9px;
          border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
          border-left: 10px solid transparent;
          transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        &::after {
          left: auto;
          right: -9px;
          border-left: none;
          border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        }
      }

      small {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
      }

      &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fa6855;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        // transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(1) {
        background: #fa6855;
        &::after {
          background: #fa6855;
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        background: #e0574f;
        &::after {
          background: #e0574f;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
            bottom: -7px;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(3) {
        background: #d7514d;
        &::after {
          background: #d7514d;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
            bottom: -3px;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(4) {
        background: #cd4b4b;
        &::after {
          background: #cd4b4b;
          box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            top: -7px;
            bottom: auto;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(5) {
        background: #c24448;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        &::after {
          background: #c24448;
          box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
          border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            top: -9px;
            bottom: auto;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
          }
        }
      }

    }

    // hover
    li:hover {
      z-index: 2;
      overflow: visible;

      &::after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
      }

      & mark {
        &::before, &::after {
          opacity: 1;
          transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

* {
  //display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaderboard">
  <h1>
    <svg class="ico-cup">
      <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
    </svg>
    Most active Players
  </h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
      <small>315</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
      <small>301</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
      <small>292</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
      <small>245</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>


<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
 C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
 C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
 c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
 c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
 c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
 c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
 c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
 c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
 c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
 C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
 c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
 L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
 c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
 C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
 C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
 c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
      </symbol>
</svg>
```

I am trying to pull data from the Db and display the top 5 in the leaderboard.here is the php in the html that i tried to execute:

```html
<?php
 session_start();

  mysql_connect('localhost','cl29-demodb','*****') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('cl29-demodb') or die(mysql_error());

  $sql = "select EmployeeName,Total_points_Rewarded from EmployeeTable
  order by LevelFieldTotal desc
  LIMIT 10 ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "" . $data['EmployeeName'] . " " . $data['Total_points_Rewarded'] . ".";

  }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DailyUI #019 - Leaderboard</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lbred/css/reset.css">

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lbred/css/style.css">





  </head>

  <body>


<div class="leaderboard">
  <h1>
    <svg class="ico-cup">
      <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
    </svg>
  Leaderboard
  </h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
      <small>315</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
      <small>301</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
      <small>292</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
      <small>245</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>


<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
 C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
 C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
 c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
 c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
 c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
 c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
 c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
 c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
 c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
 C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
 c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
 L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
 c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
 C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
 C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
 c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
      </symbol>
</svg>




  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I want to echo the top5 in the leaderboard.At the moment this is what it looks like.

Kindly help.I am using mysql here.

Comment: What would be the problem?

Comment: 1: whats the problem? 2: Stop using mysql_* functions!!!!! Use mysqli or PDO instead, since mysql is deprecated and isn't supported anymore. Oh and where you want to display the $data? You fill the variable, but you don't display it anywhere...

Comment: Thanks .I will start using sqli in future. Here the problem is i am not able to echo the fetch  variable in the leaderboard to display the top 5.

Comment: Is there a error message? (See me answer below, may it help ...) Oh yes and don't miss to replace the stars with your password :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, just replace your php code with this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    mysql_connect('localhost','cl29-demodb','*****') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('cl29-demodb') or die(mysql_error());

      $sql = "select EmployeeName,Total_points_Rewarded from EmployeeTable
      order by LevelFieldTotal desc
      LIMIT 10 ";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $html = '';
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $html .= '<li><mark>'.$data['EmployeeName'].'</mark>';
        $html .= '<small>'.$data['Total_points_Rewarded'].'</small></li>';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DailyUI #019 - Leaderboard</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lbred/css/reset.css">

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lbred/css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>


<div class="leaderboard">
  <h1>
    <svg class="ico-cup">
      <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
    </svg>
  Leaderboard
  </h1>
  <ol>

    <?php echo $html;?>
  </ol>
</div>


<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
    C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
    C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
    c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
    c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
    c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
    c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
    c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
    c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
    c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
    C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
    c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
    L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
    c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
    C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
    C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
    c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
      </symbol>
</svg>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you changed..? And still not a good answer, mysql_* functions shouldn't be used anymore. Oh yes and for you too: your data won't be displayed anywhere.

Comment: @Twinfriends I placed `ol` and `li` tags ... just like the wanted result.

Comment: after using the while statement i get error saying page isnt working

Comment: else,if i try to fetch only one row it works well without using while.Can I use the variable here and echo that variable in the html within mark and small tags. Thanks,anyway for the answers.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Try to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array. If you want to use fetch_array take out the while loop and use a foreach($row as $r) {}. Take a look at this tread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed then you'll understand much better what fetch_array is doing. And sorry i let fetch_array in my answer, didn't thought about that.

Comment: nothing to be sry. I am able to pull the top 5 through a while statement using mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: but not able to echo it in the leaderboard.i will modify the question above,jus wait.

Comment: Ok, so they are printed in the top of the page.

Comment: I`ll edit my answer then. Try with my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect.Works great now. Thanks  a lot .God bless.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a (in my opinion) better Version of your Code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "cl129-demodb", "**************", "cl129-demodb");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "select EmployeeName,Total_points_Rewarded from EmployeeTable
  order by LevelFieldTotal desc
  LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, ASSOC)) {
    echo '<mark>'.$row["EmployeeName"].'</mark><br>';
    echo '<small>'.$row["Total_points_Rewarded"].'</small><br>';
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

I rewrote it for you with mysqli. Also i added an echo in the while loop, so the data will be displayed. If you want to save it in a variable as you've done it, just add your $data part again and then use echo $data; anywhere where you want the list to be displayed. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you so much.But ur code isnot working .I have most part of my code in  the web app sql so will change to sqli later.

Comment: Thanks that u rewrote it. I Appreciate it.