# All Params Not Being Passed

Tags: php, sql-server, hyperlink

I am using php to create a hyperlink, and pass 3 params when the hyperlink is clicked.  My issue with the syntax below is that only the 1st param is passsed, the other 2 are ignored.

What should I alter in the syntax below so that all 3 params are passed?

```
    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >Name </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">User ID </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Dollar Amt </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price 1 </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price 2 </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price 3 </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Price 4 </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Items Sold </th>';
    echo '  <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Items On Sale</th>';
    echo '</tr>';  

while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['User ID'] . 
    '</td><td>' . "$".round($Row['Dollar Amt']) . '</td><td>' . "$".round($Row['Price 1']) . 
    '</td><td>'. "$".round($Row['Price 2']) . '</td><td>'. "$".round($Row['Price 3']) . 
    '</td><td>'. "$".round($Row['Price 4']) . '</td><td>' . $Row['Items Sold'] . 
    '</td><td><a href="Test.php?name='.$Row['Name'].'"&begin=".$begin"&finish=".$finish>'.$Row['Items On Sale'].'</a></td></tr>';
}
```

The above runs a sql server stored procedure and I am using echo to create a table and return to my page. That process works as it should. The only issue is that only name is passed into the url when clicked not the 2 dates that I also want to pass.

**NOT** a duplicate, that is pertinate to mysql and I am using mssql.  Also, the linked duplicate talks about returning rows, now passing parameters.  My issue is that only the name parameter is passed when clicked. Please remove the duplicate flag.

**EDIT**
The variables are defined like so:

```
$begin = $_GET['begin'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while ($row = mysql\_fetch\_array($result)) - how many loops are being performed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed)

Comment: You have spaces in your column-names, that's bad practice - you should wrap those in ticks in the query. Without seeing the query, I'm taking a wild stab and guessing that its the issue.

Comment: I feel the question/code is incomplete. Are you trying to pass something in an insert/update/delete/select?

Comment: @Matt the OP is using mssql not mysql. Two different animals here. Please remove that flag and comment

Comment: we also don't know what the query is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - the above runs a sql server stored procedure and I am using echo to create a table and return to my page.  That process works as it should.  The only issue is that only name is passed into the url when clicked not the 2 dates that I also want to pass.

Comment: you've a (new) answer below, see that. If that doesn't solve it, you'll need to post your query and the procedure for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing double-quote `"` and single-quote `'`. Replace last line of your code inside while loop with following and it should work as expected.

```
'</td><td><a href="Test.php?name='.$Row['Name'].'&begin='.$begin.'&finish='.$finish.'">'.$Row['Items On Sale'].'</a></td></tr>';
```

From your post edit, try this:

```
'</td><td><a href="Test.php?name='.$Row['Name'].'&begin='.$begin.'&finish='.$end.'">'.$Row['Items On Sale'].'</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: that passes begin, and that passes in the text for end, but not the value

Comment: @IcyPopTarts Incomplete code. Try with this. I can't see `$begin` and `$finish` variables defined. `'</td><td><a href="Test.php?name='.$Row['Name'].'&begin='.$Row['begin'].'&finish='.$Row['finish'].'">'.$Row['Items On Sale'].'</a></td></tr>';`

Comment: @IcyPopTarts Try with `$Row['begin']` & `$Row['finish']` as I showed in above comment, if that doesn't work than show full code. Where have you defined `$begin` and `$finish` variables.

Comment: I edited my post to show how they are defined.  They are captured from `$_GET`

Comment: @IcyPopTarts You are using `$finish` instead of `$end`. You should use `$end`. Check that.

Comment: That still does not pass in the value for `$end` the query string reads `Test.php?name=Red%20Shirt,%20One.&begin=2017-02-01&end=`

Comment: Double check it. If still doesn't solve the problem, check if `$end` is set, you can use php debugging function `var_dump($_GET['end'])` to check if `$_GET['end']` and `$end` has any value or you can also use conditional `isset($end)`. Just check the `$end` value just before while loop.

Comment: @IcyPopTarts Show me code you are using after change. Because I noticed that you also replaced `finish` query  parameter with `end`, I told you just to change php variable `$finish` in case and the `.` before `&begin` also not expected. Anyway show me your replacement.

Comment: Good catch - my end date variable was null.