# Output is array, how to fix this?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I am selecting some data from Mysql which I want to echo out, but I don't know how..

**Code**

```
<?php

// Database connection
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/config.php");
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/opendb.php");

// News 1
$searchroutenews1 = "SELECT newsid FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '1'";
$handlenews1 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenews1);
$news1 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenews1);
$searchroutenewsimg1 = "SELECT newsimg FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '1'";
$handlenewsimg1 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenewsimg1);
$NewsImg1 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenewsimg1);

// News 2
$searchroutenews2 = "SELECT newsid FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '2'";
$handlenews2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenews2);
$news2 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenews2);
$searchroutenewsimg2 = "SELECT newsimg FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '2'";
$handlenewsimg2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenewsimg2);
$NewsImg2 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenewsimg2);

// News 3
$searchroutenews3 = "SELECT newsid FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '3'";
$handlenews3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenews3);
$news3 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenews3);
$searchroutenewsimg3 = "SELECT newsimg FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id = '3'";
$handlenewsimg3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $searchroutenewsimg3);
$NewsImg3 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenewsimg3);

?>
```

After this I require_once this in an other file, and then I echo the variables $news1, $news2, $news3, $NewsImg1, $NewsImg2 and $NewsImg3. But if I echo this variables out now it says: array.

Comment: Use 1 query and loop the fetch.. `SELECT newsid, newsimg FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id between 1 and 3`. When in doubt about what an array has use `print_r` or `var_dump` on it. That will show you the indices so you can access it accordingly.

Comment: yes those are arrays. you need to learn about how to get values from arrays in php.

Comment: You also need to learn to stop abusing `$GLOBALS` like that. Grab your database handle if you must, and assign it to a shorter variable you can use. `$db->query(...)` is way, *way* more readable than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php 
you can find there **mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array** mysqli_fetch_row always return array so now you can't echo array thats why it gives you array.

You can try **foreach loop** or **for loop** or **while loop** to display your data. there are also various methods to get array value.

Below is an example you can use.

```
while ($news1 = mysqli_fetch_row($handlenews1)) {
    echo $news1[0];
}
```

Comment: `while ($news1) {` infinite loop most likely.

Comment: mysql_fetch_row retrieves and returns the next row it's not infinite loop you can check it in manual and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed here

Comment: But if you assign it to a variable, then use the *variable*, not the function as the argument, you'll have an infinite loop, because the variable will always be 'true', and hold the first row - it won't ever iterate. Try it, and you'll see ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed it. I am doing now: <?php echo $news1[0] ?>

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch all this information via a single query, instead of the 6 you currently are running. Then it's a matter of putting `mysqli_fetch_*()` as the argument of a while, as you'll then fetch all the rows, until that function returns null - at which point you've fetched all the rows returned by the query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT newsid, newsimg FROM NewsHomepage WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['newsid']." ".$row['newsimg'];
}
```

Change however you need it to be displayed inside the `while` loop, and use the two variables as they are inside.

Alternatively, you can use `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 3` instead, but using `IN (1, 2, 3)` can more easily be changed to the exact ids you need.

- http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look into this, because these 6 queries were not really handy.. ;-)