# Use database information as dropdownlist option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a website for school about MLB with a database. But now I want information in the database as an option in a dropdownlist. This is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" 
sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-16x16.png" 
sizes="16x16" />
<title>MLB: Major League Baseball</title>
<link href="css folder/MLBstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css"/>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="titel">    
    
    <img class="MLBTitel"  src="./images/MLBtitel.jpg" alt="MLBTitel" >
<div id="titeltekst">
MAJOR LEAGUE BASEBALL
    <br>    
</div>
        
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class= "menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class= "menu" href="spelers.php">Spelers</a></li>
        <li><a id = "active" class= "menu" href="teams.php">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a class= "menu" href="wedstrijden.html">Wedstrijden</a></li>
        <li><a class= "menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<br><br>        
</div>
<div id="teamtabel">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name='naamteam'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['teamnaam'] ."'>" . $row['teamnaam'] ."
</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The options would be the teamnames, but it seems like my dropdownlist is still empty: [picture of the dropdownlist on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twbQ1.png)
This is what my database looks like:
[picture of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwhN5.png)

I hope someone could help me and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try to move $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) outside of while. And use while($rows as $row) {} Or read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<title>MLB: Major League Baseball</title>
<link href="css folder/MLBstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="titel">    

<img class="MLBTitel"  src="./images/MLBtitel.jpg" alt="MLBTitel" >
<div id="titeltekst">
MAJOR LEAGUE BASEBALL
<br>    
</div>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a class= "menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class= "menu" href="spelers.php">Spelers</a></li>
    <li><a id = "active" class= "menu" href="teams.php">Teams</a></li>
    <li><a class= "menu" href="wedstrijden.html">Wedstrijden</a></li>
    <li><a class= "menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<br><br>        
</div>
<div id="teamtabel">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$dropdownlist = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$teamnaam = $row['teamnaam'];

$dropdownlist .="<option value='" . $teamnaam . "'>" . $teamnaam . "</option>";

}

if(isset($dropdownlist)){

    echo "<select name='naamteam'>";

    echo $dropdownlist;

    echo "</select>";
}
?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```