# Grab data from a single column of a table and save those data in each variable

Tags: php, mysql

I understand that the way to grab a row's data is to use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($RS);
$variable1 = $row[0];
$variable2 = $row[1];
$variable3 = $row[2];
```

But how does one obtain value from a column? I understood that to obtain column data of a particular row, one has to use while. But through `while`, How does one grab and store it in a variable like the way we can do with row data.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($RS)) {
    echo "$row[servicename] = $row[servicestatus]"; //grab data from a single column of a table
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974011/while-row-mysql-fetch-arrayresult-how-many-loops-are-being-performed) will help, you can try foreach and mysql_fetch_assoc instead of while.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* functions. They are abandoned, insecure and deprecated. They have been removed completely in newer php versions, so your code will not work in newer versions. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I will try explain as much as i can and i hope my solution can help you.

So you want to print the values of a specific column. First you will need a new array to store the values and a counter to set the position of storing values.

```
$newArray=array();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($RS)) {
    echo"<pre>";
    $newArray[$i]=$row[servicename] ; //the single column name you want is servicename
    $i++;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

After that the column values you want will be in your array `$newArray` and you can access it the normal way with a loop and set values from each field to variables like you want.

Also i would strongly recommend to use pdo or mysqli.